# Wordlist generation in ubuntu with static first characters

Tags: scripting, text

So,I wanted to ask what the easiest way is to generate a wordlist of the following:

```
Sample:/16.04.20/A22006
Sample:/16.04.20/A22029
Sample:/16.04.20/A22052
```

The number following `A` is increasing with 23
and the increase needs to be repeated for 200 times.

Can anyone help me out.
If it matters at all I am running on ubuntu.

Comment: Executing this in your Bash shell `echo XY{1..100..2}` will give you an idea, please try it.

Comment: @Quasímodo Are you sure this works with *Dash*? Looks like a *bashism* to me.

Comment: @Murphy It is a bashism. I made the assumption because new users on Ubuntu generally do not have so a minimal system such that bash would be absent.

Comment: @Quasímodo Be aware that the [default for `/bin/sh` in Debian](https://askubuntu.com/q/976485/568304) (und thus Ubuntu) is `dash`. Brace expansion is [not supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.7B) there.

Answer (score 0):

For loop with sequence will work in this case

```
for i in `seq 0 200`
do
    echo "Sample:/16.04.20/A"$((22006+(i*23)))
done
```